# Undefined offset: 1 when trying to create Sort filter

Tags: php

This is the code I have for my currently existing filter that works:

HTML:

```
 <select name="sortby" style="height: 40px;background: #e6e6e6;width:100%;border: 1px solid #ccc;">
<option value="HightoLow" @if(isset($returnData['sortby']) && $returnData['sortby'] == "HightoLow") selected @endif>Price High to Low</option>
<option value="LowtoHigh" @if(isset($returnData['sortby']) && $returnData['sortby'] == "LowtoHigh") selected @endif>Price Low to High</option>
 </select>
```

PHP (Laravel - Controller file):

```
  public function sortsearch(Request $request){

    $input = $request->all(); 

    $fees = schools::where('status','')
    ->orderBy('fees', 'asc')
    ->get()
    ->pluck('fees')
    ->toArray();


    $fees = array_unique($fees);
    $priceRanges = array();
    $minPrice = 0;
    $maxPrice = 0;
    if(count($fees) > 0){
        foreach ($fees as $key => $value) {
            $range = explode(' - ', $value);
            $priceRanges[] = $range['0'];
            $priceRanges[] = $range['1'];
        }
        $priceRanges = array_unique($priceRanges);
        $minPrice = (int) min($priceRanges) ?? 0;
        $maxPrice = (int) max($priceRanges) ?? 0;
        // dd($maxPrice);
    }

    $Ranges = array();
    if (isset($request['FeesRange']) && !empty($request['FeesRange'])) {
        $Rfees = explode(' - ',$request['FeesRange']);
    }else{
        $Ranges = explode(' - ',$request['fees']);
    }

    $returnData['Ranges'] = $Ranges;
    $returnData['Ranking'] = $Ranking;
    $returnData['sortby'] = $request['sortby'];
    $returnData['FeesRange'] = $request['FeesRange'];
    //dd($Rfees);
    $sortby=$request['sortby'];
    $search=$request['search'];
    //dd($fees);

 if (isset($request['FeesRange']) && !empty($request['FeesRange'])) {
        $result = $result->where('fees','like',$request['FeesRange']);
    } else {
        $result = $result->where(DB::raw("SUBSTRING_INDEX(fees, ' - ', 1)"), '>=', (int) $Ranges[0])
                         ->where(DB::raw("SUBSTRING_INDEX(fees, ' - ', -1)"), '<=', (int) $Ranges[1]);
    }

 if($sortby == "LowtoHigh"){
        $result = $result->orderBy('fees', 'asc');
    }else{
        $result = $result->orderBy('fees', 'desc');
    }

    $result = $result->paginate();
```

I am trying to create another filter but instead of sorting fees, it will sort by rank (eg: 24th, 23rd, 4th, 5th)

I've tried duplicating the code I had for fees but I an error: Undefined offset: 1

The error occurs at this line (not sure why it occurs on the fees code because the fees filter works):

```
                         ->where(DB::raw("SUBSTRING_INDEX(fees, ' - ', -1)"), '<=', (int) $Ranges[1]);
```

which comes from this snippet of code:

```
    if (isset($request['FeesRange']) && !empty($request['FeesRange'])) {
        $result = $result->where('fees','like',$request['FeesRange']);
    } else {
        $result = $result->where(DB::raw("SUBSTRING_INDEX(fees, ' - ', 1)"), '>=', (int) $Ranges[0])
                         ->where(DB::raw("SUBSTRING_INDEX(fees, ' - ', -1)"), '<=', (int) $Ranges[1]);
    }

    if (isset($request['PhilippinesRanking']) && !empty($request['PhilippinesRanking'])) {
        $result = $result->where('ranking_philippines','like',$request['PhilippinesRanking']);
    } else {
        $result = $result->where(DB::raw("SUBSTRING_INDEX(ranking_philippines, '', 1)"), '>=', (int) $Ranking[0])
                         ->where(DB::raw("SUBSTRING_INDEX(ranking_philippines, '', -1)"), '<=', (int) $Ranking[1]);
    }
```

I took out the "-" because the fees filter needed it.  The data in the fees database field looks like this: 10000-20000.  I don't need a hyphen for the ranking filter.

Comment: What is the value of `fees` at that point?

Comment: @Mawg This is the HTML code for the fees filter that is set by default: `<option value="HightoLow" @if(isset($returnData['sortby']) && $returnData['sortby'] == "HightoLow") selected @endif>Price High to Low</option>`.

Comment: It just sorts the items by Fees, highest to lowest.

Comment: The problem seems to be that `$Ranges[1]` is not defined. What do you get if you `var_dump($Ranges)` at that point? And, are you using an IDE with integrated debugger? Can't you just run to that line & examine the value of `$Ranges`?